# handle missing tags in XML using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm parsing a huge XML file using the code describe [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/parsing-huge-xml-file-with-lxml-etree-iterparse-in-python) and it works fine. However I realized in some cases the parent element is missing. Here is one example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
    <dblp>

    <article mdate="2011-01-11" key="journals/acta/Ernst77"> 
    <author>George W. Ernst</author>
    <title>Rules of Inference for Procedure Calls.</title>
    <journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
    <volume>8</volume> 
    <year>1977</year> 
    <pages>145-152</pages>
    <url>db/journals/acta/acta8.html#Ernst77</url>
    <ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00289246</ee>
    </article>

    <article mdate="2011-01-11" key="journals/acta/Pfaff83">
    <author>G&uuml;nther E. Pfaff</author>
    <title>The Construction of Operator Interfaces Based on Logical Input Devices.</title>
    <pages>151-166</pages>
    <year>1983</year>
    <volume>19</volume>
    <journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
    <url>db/journals/acta/acta19.html#Pfaff83</url>
    <ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00264473</ee>
    </article>
    <article mdate="2011-01-11" key="journals/acta/EngelfrietV88">
    <author>Joost Engelfriet</author>
    <author>Heiko Vogler</author>
    <title>High Level Tree Transducers and Iterated Pushdown Tree Transducers.</title>
    <pages>131-192</pages>
    <year>1988</year>
    <volume>26</volume>
    <journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
    <number>1/2</number>
    <url>db/journals/acta/acta26.html#EngelfrietV88</url>
    <ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02915449</ee>
    </article>

    <author>Antonio Gull&igrave;</author>
    <title>Clustering and ranking for web information retrieval: methodologies for searching the web.</title>
    <year>2008</year>
    <school>University of Pisa</school>
    <pages>1-137</pages>
    <isbn>978-3-8364-5657-9</isbn>
    <ee>http://d-nb.info/987753223</ee>
    
    </dblp>
```

last record is missing the start and end tag `<article>`.

in the code (provided in the link) the error comes from the function `extract_paper_elements` in the for loop `for event, element in context`. Here is the error:

```
Element dblp content does not follow the DTD, expecting (article | inproceedings | proceedings | book | incollection | phdthesis | mastersthesis | www)*, got (article article article author title year school pages isbn ee ), line 47, column 12
```

Is there any solution for such cases?
I would be also happy for a solution to find these cases (using bash commands or code). If the number of cases are not a lot, I can fix them manually!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is as you expect: Manually repair the broken XML.

There is no general repair method that you can automatically apply when you encounter an arbitrary validation error.  One might imagine some simple cases being covered automatically, but in general there can be multiple ways to address a validation error.  You typically decide which is appropriate and manually repair the XML (or fix the upstream system that produced the invalid XML).

Then you validate again and address any further issues.  This cycle repeats until no validation error remains (much like the repair of syntactical problems in a programming language does).